# Splitting string in oracle - fastest way

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, split

Does anybody know how to split string separated by ';' in a trigger, faster than this code:

```
SELECT regexp_substr('asd;asaaaad;dd;', '([^;]*)(;)', 1, level, null, 1) 
  BULK COLLECT INTO array_TREATMENT_TR_CD 
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT('asd;asaaaad;dd;', '[;]') + 1 ;
```

Comment: Seems like a fine solution to me. It returns in less than 1ms for me. Could you explain a bit more about your situation why that is not fast enough? That may increase the usefulness of the answers :-)

Comment: It is for real time environment and it is a mattter of 'could it be faster?' than 'it's not fast enough' :)

Answer (score 1):

Regexp functions are usually way slower than standard db functions. When I run your code 100.000 times it takes around 12 seconds (on my db, YMMV).

Then I created this small test:

```
declare
  type t_vc2 is table of varchar2(250) index by pls_integer;

  procedure split_str(
    p_str1      in out nocopy varchar2
  , p_str2      out           varchar2
  , p_separator in            varchar2 default ';'
  )
  is
    l_pos pls_integer;
  begin
    l_pos := instr(p_str1, p_separator);
    if nvl(l_pos, 0) = 0
    then
      p_str2 := p_str1;
      p_str1 := null;
    else
      p_str2 := substr(p_str1, 1, l_pos-1);
      p_str1 := substr(p_str1, l_pos+1);
    end if;
  end split_str;
begin
  for l_i in 1 .. 1000000
  loop
    declare
      array_TREATMENT_TR_CD    t_vc2;
      l_input varchar2(250);
      l_return varchar2(250);
    begin
      l_input := 'asd;asaaaad;dd;';
      loop
        split_str(l_input, l_return);
        if l_return is not null
        then
          array_TREATMENT_TR_CD(array_TREATMENT_TR_CD.count+1) := l_return;
        end if;
        exit when l_return is null;
      end loop;
    end;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This parses your example string 100.000 times to an array with standard db functions. It takes around 0.5 seconds. That's a significant improvement if "real time" is what you aim for.